2 excel sheet: 1) Working File, 2)Data file. Need to update "city" column in working file if there a match in data. please use excel vba
Nothing happens when I run this macro, it does not append the city column of address sheet. but the macro executed without error.
I'm expecting it will update the corresponding "City" column when comparing data to address "city name" is true. My macro:
Sub UpdateCityNames()
    Dim wsLugar As Worksheet
    Dim wsSiudad As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowLugar As Long
    Dim lastRowSiudad As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim townOrCityName As String
    
    ' Set the worksheets
    Set wsLugar = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lugar")
    Set wsSiudad = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Siudad")
    
    ' Find the last row with data in the Siudad and Lugar sheets
    lastRowLugar = wsLugar.Cells(wsLugar.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowSiudad = wsSiudad.Cells(wsSiudad.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in Siudad sheet
    For i = 1 To lastRowSiudad
        townOrCityName = wsSiudad.Cells(i, 1).Value ' Town or city name
        
        ' Loop through each row in Lugar sheet
        For j = 1 To lastRowLugar
            ' Check if the town/city name exists in the address column
            If InStr(1, wsLugar.Cells(j, 1).Value, townOrCityName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                ' Append town/city name to the city column
                wsLugar.Cells(j, 2).Value = townOrCityName
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


Have you tried to debug your code using F8? Do the last-variables contain the row number you expect? Is the town name read correctly? Is the InStr-function working?

I have the impression you're trying to re-invent VLookup(), let me show you what I mean: I have created two sheets ("Ciudad" and "Lugar"), and I'm using VLookup() for filling in the name of the town, based on postal code (I believe you're doing something similar).
"Ciudad" sheet:

"Lugar" sheet:

Hereby the corresponding VLookup() formula:
=VLOOKUP(Lugar!B1;Ciudad!$A$1:$B$2;2;FALSE)

Be careful that your table_array is based on absolute addresses: " $ A $ 1: $ B $ 2"
